# glGetPixels on Offscreen framebuffer opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I generate a PointCloud in my program, and now, I want to be able to click on a point in this point cloud rendered to my screen using OpenGL.

In order to do so, I used the trick of giving to each pixel in an offscreen render a colour based on its index in the VBO. I use the same camera for my offscreen render and my onscreen render so they move together, and when I click, I get values of my offscreen render to retrieve the position in the VBO to get the point I clicked on. This is the theory since when I click, I have only (0,0,0). I believe that means my FBO is not well renderer but I'm not sure whether it is that or if the problem comes from somewhere else...

So here are the steps. `clicFBO` is the FBO I'm using for offscreen render, and `clicTextureColorBuf` is the texture in which I write in the FBO

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &clicFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, clicFBO);
glGenTextures(1, &clicTextureColorBuf);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, clicTextureColorBuf);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, clicTextureColorBuf, 0);
GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);
```

After that, I wrote a shader that gives to each point the color of its index in the VBO...

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> reconstruction3D; //Will contain the position of my points
std::vector<float> indicesPointsVBO; //Will contain the indexes of each point
for (int i = 0; i < pts3d.size(); ++i) {
    reconstruction3D.push_back(pts3d[i].pt3d);
    colors3D.push_back(pt_tmp);
    indicesPointsVBO.push_back(((float)i / (float)pts3d.size() ));
}

GLuint clicVAO, clicVBO[2];
glGenVertexArrays(1, &clicVAO);
glGenBuffers(2, &clicVBO[0]);
glBindVertexArray(clicVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, clicVBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, reconstruction3D.size() * sizeof(cv::Point3f), &reconstruction3D[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, clicVBO[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesPointsVBO.size() * sizeof(float), &indicesPointsVBO[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

and the vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in float col;

out float Col;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform int pointSize;

void main()
{
    gl_PointSize = pointSize;
    gl_Position =  projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0);

    Col = col;
}
```

And the Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;
in float Col;
void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(Col, Col, Col ,1.0);
}
```

And this is how I render this texture:

```
    glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, clicFBO);
    clicShader.use();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    clicShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
    clicShader.setMat4("view", view);
     model = glm::mat4();
    clicShader.setMat4("model", model);
    clicShader.setInt("pointSize", pointSize);

    glBindVertexArray(clicVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (GLsizei)reconstruction3D.size());
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

And then, when I click, I Use this piece of Code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, clicFBO);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
int width = 11, height = 11;
std::array<GLfloat, 363> arry{ 1 };

glReadPixels(Xpos - 5, Ypos - 5, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &arry);
for (int i = 0; i < 363; i+=3) { // It's 3 time the same number anyways for each number
    std::cout << arry[i] << " "; // It gives me only 0's
}
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, clicFBO);
```

I know the error might be really stupid but I still have some problems with how OpenGL works.

I put what I thought was necessary to understand the problem (without extending too much), but if you need more code, I can write it too.

I know this is not a question in which you can say Yes or No and it's more like debugging my program, but since I really don't find from where the problem comes from, I'm looking toward someone who can explain to me what I did wrong. I do not necessarily seek the solution itself, but clues that could help me understand where my error is ...

Comment: I once did something similar and I cannot remember that I explicitly made it "off-screen". I just used a different FBO for that what I called pickmap. I googled a bit and found this tutorial: [Picking with an OpenGL hack](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/). Btw. meanwhile we kicked this tech. as it was too slow. (Instead, we do intersection tests on CPU side.) Funny enough - the tutorial mentioned this weakness as well: _it might introduce noticeable framerate drops_ Yepp, I can confirm this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I will take a look at that!
To do the intersection test, I should create a data structure using Octree and so one. Since I do lots of calcul and I just want to see the datas, the FPS drop won't be annoying to me actually.
Thanks again!

Comment: In our case, we had triangle soups separated in groups (bodies). The amount of data is something which can be callenging. (CPU cannot provide that high amount of parallelization like GPU.) Hence, some kind of branch-and-bounding is most times necessary. If data is stored in a classical scene graph (with bounding spheres), this can be exploited. In your case, oct-trees might be a sufficient approach. The rest is 3d math. As you use `glm`, most of needed functions are probably there or can be built on top.

Comment: I already built an Octree using glm for another project.
The second method is to use glUnproject 2 times, create a ray between the 2 points Unprojected, and then see which point is the closer to this ray using octree, right? 
Since I think I am really close to achieve with the method i'm currently using, I would like to finish. If really I don't find the way, i'll do the other (And if I have too much problem, I'll try the new method). But for now, I'll be insistent on resolving my error^^'

Comment: Regarding ray casting, for points I do it a bit different: I check points against a frustum (frustum like in view frustum). The advantage: I can use the same test for picking and rubberband selection. For picking, I define a rather small frustum to consider something like a constant (distance independent) point size. (This matches perfectly my rendering where I use `glPointSize()`.) Btw. it is quite easy to define this pick frustum from the view frustum and some additional scaling of l, r, t, b (4 of the 6 parameters which are usual to define view frustums) i.e. I don't need `glUnproject()`.

Comment: Thanks for these precisions! :)

Comment: As I am sometimes bound to the old API I am using stencil for this (no FBO no render to texture as that is not working on Intel HD) You might try the same here an [example in old API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214) so you just need to update shaders a bit ...  but I think Ripi2's answer nails your problem as you are not rendering the second buffer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
There were 2 failures in my code :
The first one is that in OpenGL, there is an Y inversion between the image and the framebuffer. So in order to pick the good point, you have to flip Y using the size of the viewport :  I did it like this :

```
GLint m_viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, m_viewport);
int YposTMP = m_viewport[3] - Ypos - 1;
```

The second one is the use of 
`glReadPixels(Xpos - 2, Ypos - 2, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixels[0]);`, the 6th parameter must be `GL_FLOAT` since the datas i'm returning are float.

Thanks all!
Best regards,
R.S

Answer (score 1):

Using a framebuffer object [FBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) to store a "object identifier" is a cool method. But also want to see the objects, right? Then you must render also to the default frame buffer (let me call it "defFB", which is not a FBO).

Because you need to render to two different targets, you need one of these techniques:

- Draw objects twice (e.g. with two `glDrawArrays` calls), one to the FBO and a second one to the defFB.
- Draw to two FBO's images at once and later blit one of then (with colors) to the defFB.

For the first technique you may use a texture attached to a FBO (as you currently do). Or you can use a "Renderbuffer" and draw to it.

The second approach needs a second "out" in the fragment shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec3 color; //GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
layout(location = 1) out vec3 objID; //GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1
```

and setting the two attachments with `glDrawBuffers`.

For the blit part, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103942/3871028).

Note that both "out" have the same format, `vec3` in this example.

**A fail** in your code is that you set a `RGB` texture format and also use this format at `glReadPixels`, but your "out" in the FS is `vec4` instead of `vec3`.

More concerns are:

- Check the completeness with [glCheckFramebufferStatus](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glCheckFramebufferStatus)
- Using a "depth attachment" to the FBO may be needed, even it will not be used for reading.
- Disabling the depth test will put all elements if the frame. Your point-picking will select the last drawn, not the nearest.

Comment: Mmmmh, Thanks for your answer, but Actually, I render on the default framebuffer. I can effectively see what I want to see, and my problem only occurs on the offscreen render.
I had already the good render and I wanted to add to this functionnal code the fact that I could click on a point . 

-I checked the Framebuffer status and I have no error  
-I added a depth attachment to my FBO   
- I tried to disable the depth test  
- I changed the vec4 for vec3  
But nothing changed :( 

Thanks a lot anyway!